# php foreach glob multiple extensions

Tags: php, foreach, glob

There has got to be a better way to write this:

```
<?php $imagecounter = "no";
    foreach (glob("images/*.jpg") as $image)    {
    $imagecounter = "yes";
    }
    foreach (glob("images/*.png") as $image)    {
    $imagecounter = "yes";
    }
    foreach (glob("images/*.gif") as $image)    {
    $imagecounter = "yes";
    }
    if ($imagecounter == "yes"){Create gallery}?>
```

That folder might have zip or pdf files too that should not create a gallery

Comment: So basiclly you want to check if there are any images inside the folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if(glob("images/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE))
{
  //create gallery
}
```

And that's about it :)

Answer (score -2):

I think you want to remove foreach looping and check that in images folder any extension from "jpg,png,gif".
so you can use ternary operator. Here is sample code.

```
$imagecounter = glob("img/*.jpg")?'yes':$imagecounter;
$imagecounter = glob("img/*.png")?'yes':$imagecounter;
$imagecounter = glob("img/*.gif")?'yes':$imagecounter;

if ($imagecounter == "yes"){Create gallery}
```

?>
If i assume wrong, let me know mate.