# List only image files in files drop down list

Tags: php

I have this code below that will list all files in the images folder. How do I list only certain extensions in the list such as jpg, png, gif.

```
<select name="s1">
  <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
    <?php 
       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/*') as $filename) {
         $filename = basename($filename);
         echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
       }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`glob()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) takes in 2 parameters. The documentation for the second parameter flags show:

> GLOB_BRACE - Expands {a,b,c} to match 'a', 'b', or 'c'

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969187/php-foreach-glob-multiple-extensions) for more info:

```
foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename){
   $filename = basename($filename);
   echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need an `if` statement and a condition to filter the results. A regular expression is particularly useful here. Something like this should do what you want:

```
<select name="s1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
    <?php 
        foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/*') as $filename){
            $filename = basename($filename);
            if (preg_match('/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/i', $filename)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Note: I have formatted your code to use consistent indentation to make it readable.

Comment: thanks but i received Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in   if (preg_match(/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/i, $filename)) {

Comment: @gtroop Oops; left off the quotation marks. Please see my edit.

Comment: @gtroop Glad to help. [FrankerZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44857116/2057919) is also very good and may work better if your requirements are simple enough.